# Share Notepad++ NppFTP profiles

Tags: notepad++

I have 4 computers I use in my house that I use for freelancing.  I have been racking my brain trying to find a way to share the profiles from one to another without having to drag and drop the files from one profile to another.

Is there a way to change the NppFTP file location so that it opens from multiple locations?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install file sync tool (OneDrive? Dropbox? there is more, it is different question) to all 4 machines. Maybe you have something already. Or alternatively try your Roaming folder in your Windows user profile, if it already synchronizes between your machines. Shortly: make some sync working and understand which folder in your PC's is synchronized.
2. The second problem is how to sync only NppFTP files and not all other config files in the same folder. You have to [create hard link (junction)](https://superuser.com/a/484062/287473) to NppFTP configuration files placed in synchronized folder. (Linked example shows hard-linking directory, you have to do that for each of your config files instead.) This will make them visible to synchronization process. (You can test it even by editing them manually.)