# Link a folder to another folder without using space

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, box.com

I want to link one folder from a part of the drive to another folder that syncs it with Box, retaining the original copy and without using any additional space. Shortcut files don't work, so I am looking for another method.

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an NTFS junction?](http://superuser.com/questions/484061/how-to-create-an-ntfs-junction)

Comment: What does "syncs it with Box" mean? Please be more specific. Original copy of what?

Comment: @kreemoweet I think he means the [cloud storage provider, Box](https://www.box.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NTFS junctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point). You can make NTFS junction with special software. I recommend [Link Shell Extension (LSE)](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html). It is freeware and easy to use. It also has good documentation with screenshots of all steps.