# Using Laptop Solely for VNC Connection to Desktop

Tags: laptop, remote-desktop, desktop, vnc

**Question**: Would it be reasonable to use a laptop solely as a Virtual Network Connection (VNC) client of my main desktop's VNC server? If so, what would be the best method to use?

**Background**: I have a laptop (Surface Pro) and a desktop computer (self-built, i5-4690K) that I use pretty equally for productivity. I do a lot of work on the laptop when I'm away from my apartment, but prefer to use the desktop when I'm home because it has more processing power and a nice setup.

So, I'm rather tired of making sure everything is in sync between the two computers since I switch frequently between the two. Programs, files, settings, preferences - I have to download and set up everything twice, once for each computer. Plus, there are times where I'd like to do some processor intensive tasks (3d modeling, video editing, running bulky IDEs, etc.), but am away from my desktop.

Let me know if there would be any better solution than using a VNC server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share user and storage locations like so:

1. Set up your desktop as a Windows Server with a Domain Controller.
2. Set up your laptop as a client computer of that domain.
3. Create a new user in that domain such that you can login with that user on either device.
4. Make any folder you want to share a [junction point](https://superuser.com/a/484062/9666) of a mounted network share.
5. Where possible, make sure you save to shared locations.

This results in one session on both devices. Mind corruption, avoid using both devices simultaneously...

Comment: Thanks, Tom. What would this be considered, exactly? As in, what would I look up for further research?

Comment: @MichaelHays: These are instructions; if a part is unclear, feel free to ask about it. As for research, you could attempt to set this up to try this out in a virtual machine. Make sure you don't activate the Windows in the VM if you do that.