# Create windows sybmolic link shortcut

Tags: windows-7, windows, ms-dos

Can a Windows synonym shortcut be created so that the location "/home/" maps to "c:\" drive ?

Another way, if I navigate via DOS to "/home/" then "c:/" drive is navigation target.

Note : I'm not looking for a cygwin suggestion as this needs to be navigable via DOS.

Update : I've renamed this question I wasn't aware of "symbolic link" term.

Comment: Take a look here, this seems like it will answer your question http://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt

Comment: Do you mean `synonym shortcut` or `symbolic link`?

Comment: @Ramhound I think its "symbolic link" as this will allow my to navigate to dir with String of my choosing ?

Comment: @NathanKerr posted link refer's to environment variables ? I don't think environment variables can be used to set shortcut paths?

Comment: The best way to get an answer to your question is to update your question to use the correct term.  A symbolic link would allow you to create a symbolic representation to `Folder A` and `Folder B`.  In other words `Folder B` would be `Folder A`.

Comment: @blue-sky True, i was thinking of use within a script, however the "doskey" command may be of some use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use NTFS, you can create a [junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point). [Here's how to create it.](https://superuser.com/q/484061/397839)

NTFS also supports [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) in Vista and later, and can be created using `mklink` command.